# Android Kotlin migration: Unresolved Reference

Tags: java, android, kotlin, build, reference

I'm migrating my multi-module Android app from Java to Kotlin, and being in an advanced stage have come across with the next issue:

Android Studio complains with "Reference not found" from class from another module when building. The weird thing is that there is no Lint underlined text in red, in fact intellisense (auto-complete) detects all the packages until "AppSettings" with no problems, but cannot build.

I can't paste much code, but at least a screenshot of the problem.

[image: AppSettings unresolved reference]

Any suggestions? (already cleaned project, reset cache and built again and the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

OK, in the end it was extremely simple and stupid. In the "Global" module, and due to a previous problem, I had commented the next gradle line:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
```

And after uncommenting it now the problem got resolved.

Thanks to me :)